# In bash, how would I say, If a file does not end in "*_01-1.html" delete it?

Tags: bash, shell

Google is not helping me and I can't figure out the syntax.

```
for file in *_01.html
  do 
    <I want to say if a file does NOT end in *_01.html OR *.pdf then delete it>
  done
```

so in one directory, I'm trying to get it to loop through each file and if that file does NOT end in whatever_01.html OR  whatever.pdf then delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*_01.html|*.pdf)
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you, how about a way to delete .html files that do not follow the format (paystub_##-#.html) for example I want to remove all files in a directory that do are not formatted like so. paystub_01-1.html would stay but paystub_01.html would be removed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this recursively (say, in all subdirs as well), please do this:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*_01.html' -exec rm {} \;
```

find is a command which searches for files in subdirs by default. Here you say: "please find entities **not** ending with '_01.html' which are not dirs and pass each entry as the argument to 'rm' command".